# What algorithm to use for balancing amount of items

Tags: algorithm

I have an array of Ingredients. All Macros values are in grams per 100g.
Let's say I have to consume per day 220g proteins, 60g fats, 230g carbs.

What would be the algorithm to set correct amount for ingredients to get as close as possible to daily amount of Macros? Is there some existing algorithm for that?

```
   var ingredients = [
      Ingredient(
        name: "Chicken breast",
        macros: Macros(
          proteins: 23.1,
          fats: 1.2,
          carbs: 0
        )
      ),
      Ingredient(
        name: "Carrots",
        macros: Macros(
          proteins: 0.9,
          fats: 11.4,
          carbs: 0.2
        )
      ),
      Ingredient(
        name: "Onions",
        macros: Macros(
          proteins: 0.9,
          fats: 0,
          carbs: 11.5
        )
      ),
      Ingredient(
        name: "Oil (grape seed)",
        macros: Macros(
          proteins: 0,
          fats: 100,
          carbs: 0
        )
      ),
      Ingredient(
        name: "Rice (brown)",
        macros: Macros(
          proteins: 7.5,
          fats: 2.4,
          carbs: 74
        )
      )
    ]
```

Comment: Without constraints, algebra.  With constraints, [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) or [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

Comment: This is certainly helpful. Thanx!

Comment: You have five ingredients and only three requirements, so it's very likely that there will be not a single answer but a formula (with up to 2 degrees of freedom) of solutions.

Comment: Yeah. It's simplified example. There might be much more ingredients and multiple meals per day. My idea is to get the closest optimization possible. So I need an algorithm for that.  Or some hint to what to look for :)

Comment: Can you show some examples with this sample data?

Comment: Following this example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790921/balancing-recipes-ingredients-through-a-system-of-linear-equations-is-it-the-r

So far I've come up with this equation:

23,1a + 0.9b + 0.9c + 0d + 7.5e = 22000 and
11.2a + 11.4b + 0c +100d + 2.4e = 6000 and
0a + 0.2b + 11.5c + 0d + 74e = 32000 and

a = chicken breast
b = carrots
c = onions
d = oil
e = rice

Values from my original ingredients. Don't know how to proceed further.